# Setting callback on Polymer iron-ajax

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

Is it possible to set/change the callbacks on iron-ajax?
I have a variable number of requests to make with different callbacks for each.

Comment: IMO, you should make one `iron-ajax` for each _response_ you are interested in, instead of trying to make one `iron-ajax` manage multiple responses.

Comment: guys, why do we even need `iron-ajax` DOM element in the first place? why not call api's directly through normal `fetch` or `xhr`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott has said in the comment you should use a separate iron-ajax for each request.  HOWEVER, if you want to make requests dynamically, I tend to use a dynamically created iron-request - if only because it returns a promise and I can carry that around.  Here is a little example

```
    var dataPromise = new Promise(function(accept, reject) {
      var sendOptions = {
        url: '/api/queries',
        method: 'POST',
        handleAs: 'json',
        headers: {'content-type': 'application/json'}
      };
      body = {};
      body.name = name;
      if (useId) {
        body.id = parent.id;
      }
      if (useDates) {
        body.startdate = parent.startdate;
        body.enddate = parent.enddate;
      }
      sendOptions.body = body;
      var request = document.createElement('iron-request');
      request.send(sendOptions).then(function() {
        accept(request.response);
      });
    });
```

and then I can pass the `dataPromise` around, and when I want need the results of the request I do (in my case in a completely separate element) ...

```
  open: function(dataPromise, params, x, y) {
    var self = this;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    dataPromise.then(function(data) {
      self.title = data.name;
      self.heading = data.heading;
      self.data = data.data;
      self.$.griddialog.open();
    });
    this.params = params;
  },
```

Comment: wow that looks terrible to me. mean, whole request-through-element approach.  this can be easily done with fetch() right, or just normal XHR? now u have to create a wrapper over DOM element to make ajax request. rediculous..